# Can't install mercurial on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, macports, mercurial

I can't install Mercurial.  I am getting this error:

> --->  Computing dependencies for mercurial
>   Error: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?

Answer (score 5):

(I'm not using Mac myself, but I've seen these support requests before...)

Please try one of our [binary packages for Mac OS X](http://mercurial.berkwood.com/). Normal users should not be bothered with installing compilers and make just to use Mercurial...

Also, `easy_install` route is anything but easy unless you have a compiler and the required Python header files installed since `easy_install` will want to compile the C extensions we use. Better to stick with a binary package, IMHO.

Comment: Alas, I don't see any downloads at the other end of that link. Is https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads/ a better place to find binary packages for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to install Mercurial via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). Since MacPorts builds its ports from source (at least mine does, and yours seems to also), you'll also need to install the Mac OS X developer tools. You can do this by finding your Mac OS X install disc and [installing Xcode from it](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeCoexistence/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Basics/Basics.html).

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to install?

I would suggest going the easy_install route.

```
$ sudo easy_install -U mercurial
```

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download#Using_easy_install

Answer (score 1):

Is this compiling from source or installing one of the handy Leopard and Snow Leopard binaries?

Moreover, have you installed the Mac development kit?  (Macintoshes, like Windows machines, do not normally come with development software installed.)  If so, have you moved anything later?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to install the program 'make' from MacPorts. Either that or it can't find it in one of the directories that it lists in path.

You can verify if you have make just by typing 'make -v' in a Terminal.

Comment: Which will show whether make is in any directory in $PATH.  It still could be somewhere else.

Comment: true.. but then we can at least verify whether make is callable by the build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Tereno:
I don't have make, how I can install?

David:
I don't have snow leopard , I have leopard 10.5.8, I didn't install Mac development kit.
From where I can find Mac Development Kit?

Comment: The development kit came with your computer, assuming you have the original CDs.  You can also download it from apple.com.  For MacOSX 10.5.8, you'd want to download the 10.5 version from http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads/.

Comment: You should definitely get the development kit from the Apple site as the one on the Leopard CD is older and I think you need a later version for Macports see http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html