# Can't install Mercurial on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, mac, python, mercurial

When selecting the volume in the installation program it says "You cannot install Merucrial on this volume. Mercurial requires Apple Python 2.6". I tried installing the latest version of Python from python.org but no luck.

Regards

Peter

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the python you installed from python.org is installed but the path it is in is not where mercurial for Mac is looking.  Try the command `which python` to see which path to python is found.

The best way to get python 2.6 on MAC in a place that MAC apps can find it is `sudo port install python26` on the command line and that will do the trick.

Comment: Opened terminal, typed the command sudo port install python26 and get the error
sudo: port: command not found

Is the python26 you are referring to something I need to download? I downloaded the python DMG which has a .mpkg file in it.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Port is a package install system - it needs to be installed itself - here is the link http://www.macports.org/

Comment: $ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python

After installing Port...

$ sudo port install python26
Error: Unable to open port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?
Before reporting a bug, first run the command again with the -d flag to get complete output.

Comment: Looks like this is now a duplicate thread - the answer to your exact situation is here: http://superuser.com/questions/67483/cant-install-mercurial-on-mac-os-x